# The first of the id's in the table created while seeding is null

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6, and when I try seeding some data the GuideId and DriverID returns null. I am not sure it is related or not but I am trying to create a entity called Tour and it has two employee with the same model. Also GuideID and DriverID always has unique property when I don't declare it otherwise with FluentApi.

[My Database looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V49ME.png)

This is my seed data looks like :

```
        public static void SeedTour(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Tour>().HasData(
    new Tour() { ID = 1, VehicleID = 1, Type = "Kara", Name = "Jeep Safari Turu", GuideID = 4, DriverID = 3, Price = 100, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, Status = Entity.Enums.Status.Created, Description = "Antalya'nın doğal güzelliklerini keşfetmek için harika bir tur" },
    new Tour() { ID = 2, VehicleID = 2, Type = "Köylü", Name = "Köy Turu", GuideID = 4, DriverID = 3, Price = 250, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, Status = Entity.Enums.Status.Created, Description = "Antalya'nın doğal güzelliklerini keşfetmek için çok kötü bir tur" },
    new Tour() { ID = 3, VehicleID = 3, Type = "Deniz", Name = "Yat Turu", GuideID = 4, DriverID = 3, Price = 500, CreatedDate = DateTime.Now, Status = Entity.Enums.Status.Created, Description = "Antalya'nın denzilerini keşfetmek için harika bir tur" }
        );
        }
```

This is my Tour entity looks like :

```
    public class Tour : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public int Price { get; set; }

        //Relational Properties
        public int? VehicleID { get; set; }
        public Vehicle? Vehicle { get; set; }
        public int? GuideID { get; set; }
        public Employee? Guide { get; set; }
        public int? DriverID { get; set; }

        public Employee? Driver { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Ticket>? Tickets { get; set; }
    }
```

And without this code, I can not migrate the data properly, don't know why.

```
            builder.Entity<Tour>()
                .HasIndex(u => u.DriverID)
                .IsUnique(false);
            builder.Entity<Tour>()
                .HasIndex(u => u.GuideID)
                .IsUnique(false);
```

Can you guys please help me out.

I tried different annotations but nothing worked.

Comment: So if you delete those 3 records and re-run the seeding, it creates the 3 records where the first record is missing the Guide and Driver IDs?

Comment: Yes exactly that happens, and I have no clue why.